# Coding standards for custom theme functions regarding arrays passed as variables?

Tags: theming

I have created a custom theme function and almost all the data that I pass via variables is in one big array. I have documented the keys of the array fairly well. In my first pass at the module I didn't always set every key so the template is giving me some undefined index errors. Basically is it reasonable to expect the themer to have to check isset($my_array['key']) or should I make sure $my_array['key'] is always set to an empty string?

Or perhaps I shouldn't be passing so much data in an array. Instead I should be breaking it up into multiple variables?

What is a good way of dealing with values that are optional? For example if I have an event and it has an optional address (subarray) how do I pass the information to the themer that there is no address? Should I create another key called 'has_address' for example?

I there a documented coding standard for custom theme functions regarding arrays passed as variables?

Comment: Do the optional values have defaults?

Comment: No, right now the way I am retrieving the values anything optional results in some keys not being set at all.